# HTTP cammands using SIM900 modems

Tags: gprs

Iam facing problems with sim900 module.It all working fine and data is posting but SIM900A modem stop responding after hours of standby which is stoping controller instruction exeution. Please provide me the solution.

Comment: terrible description of your question. you provide no clues, no data you dont provide anything so someone can help you. if i answered your question in the same way you described it, i would say "you need to press some buttons."

Answer (score 0):

You should reset Your sim900a manually from controller every XX minutes.

```
PORTD.4=1; // power on
delay_ms(1000);
PORTD.4=0; // power off
delay_ms(5000);
PORTD.4=1; // power on again
delay_ms(5000);
```

This code has to be executed twice for reset - first time for power off, next one - to power on.